# How and where is the value of msg.value assigned?

Tags: transactions, contract-design

I'm aware that msg.value is the amount of "wei" sent to the contract according to this [page](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html). I think it's sent from a transaction so it should be defined there.

**Question:** How is the value of msg.value in a transaction is defined to have a structure like: msg.value in the contract?

Comment: It is part of the transaction, from the [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), section 4.2 "The transaction" it has a field called 'value'. 
From a contract you cant get this value with the opcode CALLVALUE (0x34), section H.2 "Instruction Set", table "30s Environmental Information" .

Answer (score 1):

This is what the crontact receive in ethereum (what the sender of the transaction pay exclude gas and miner fee).
It is in wei (1 ethereum = 10000000000000000000 wei (10^18)) wei is like satoshi a subunit more precise.

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the transaction, from the Ethereum Yellow Paper, section 4.2 "The transaction" it has a field named 'value'.

From a contract you get the value with the opcode CALLVALUE (0x34), section H.2 "Instruction Set", table "30s Environmental Information".